# Way to show errors on respective fields from Result i got from Api Endpoint and removing useEffect

Tags: reactjs, .net-core, react-query, fluent-ui

I have an api endpoint the returns me 400 Bad with Validation Errors given by FluentValidation. I want to show the errors on their respective fields for the user's information.

```
using Ardalis.ApiEndpoints;
using MediatR;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using QueryStore.Application.Queries;

namespace QueryStore.API.Endpoints.Queries;

public sealed class CreateQueryEndpoint : EndpointBaseAsync
    .WithRequest<CreateQueryCommand>
    .WithActionResult<int>
{
    private readonly IMediator _mediator;

    public CreateQueryEndpoint(IMediator mediator)
    {
        _mediator = mediator ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(mediator));
    }

    [HttpPost("/queries")]
    public override async Task<ActionResult<int>> HandleAsync([FromBody] CreateQueryCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        var result = await _mediator.Send(request, cancellationToken);

        if (!result.IsSuccess)
        {
            foreach (var error in result.Errors)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(error.Code, error.Description);
            }

            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }


        var getByIdUrl = Url.RouteUrl(GetQueryByIdEndpoint.RouteName) ?? string.Empty;

        return Created(getByIdUrl, result);
    }
}
```

This is response object i received in axios error when Validation fails:

```
{
    "data": {
        "NotEmptyValidator": [
            "'Name' must not be empty."
        ],
        "PredicateValidator": [
            "Query content must be a valid SQL query."
        ]
    },
    "status": 400,
    "statusText": "",
    "headers": {
        "content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"
    },
    "config": {
        "transitional": {
            "silentJSONParsing": true,
            "forcedJSONParsing": true,
            "clarifyTimeoutError": false
        },
        "adapter": "xhr",
        "transformRequest": [
            null
        ],
        "transformResponse": [
            null
        ],
        "timeout": 0,
        "xsrfCookieName": "XSRF-TOKEN",
        "xsrfHeaderName": "X-XSRF-TOKEN",
        "maxContentLength": -1,
        "maxBodyLength": -1,
        "env": {},
        "headers": {
            "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        "method": "post",
        "url": "https://localhost:8443/queries",
        "data": "{\"name\":\"\",\"description\":\"\",\"content\":\"xasxasxasx cdcsdcsdc casdcscdsc\",\"tags\":[]}"
    },
    "request": {}
}
```

I want a way to show this errors on my UI fields as errors for user information.

```
My UI Component:
import {
  makeStyles,
  shorthands,
  Field,
  Input,
  Button,
  tokens,
  useId,
  useToastController,
  Toast,
  ToastTitle,
  Toaster,
} from "@fluentui/react-components";
import { Add16Filled } from "@fluentui/react-icons";
import axios from "axios";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useMutation } from "react-query";

interface CreateQuery {
  name: string;
  description: string;
  content: string;
  tags: string[];
}
interface CreateQueryProps {
  setComponent: (component: string) => void;
}

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    display: "flex",
    fontWeight: tokens.fontWeightBold,
    flexDirection: "column",
    ...shorthands.gap("20px"),
    maxWidth: "600px",
    marginLeft: "20px",
    marginTop: "20px",
  },

  primaryButton: {
    marginRight: "8px",
  },
});

export default function CreateQuery({ setComponent }: CreateQueryProps) {
  const classes = useStyles();

  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [description, setDescription] = useState("");
  const [content, setContent] = useState("");
  const [tags, setTags] = useState([] as string[]);

  const handleTags = (tags: string) => {
    let tagsArr: string[] = tags.split(",");
    setTags(tagsArr);
  };

  const createQuery = async ({
    name,
    description,
    content,
    tags,
  }: CreateQuery) => {
    const response = await axios.post("https://localhost:8443/queries", {
      name,
      description,
      content,
      tags,
    });
    return response.data;
  };

  const mutation = useMutation(createQuery);

  const submitData = () => {
    mutation.mutate({ name, description, content, tags });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (mutation.isSuccess) {
      setComponent("home");
    }
  }, [mutation.isSuccess])

  function extractMessages(data: any) {
    const messages: any = [];
  
    // Recursive function to traverse the data structure
    function extractMessagesRecursively(obj: any) {
      for (const key in obj) {
        if (Array.isArray(obj[key])) {
          obj[key].forEach((item: string) => {
            if (typeof item === 'string') {
              messages.push(item);
            } else if (typeof item === 'object') {
              extractMessagesRecursively(item);
            }
          });
        } else if (typeof obj[key] === 'object') {
          extractMessagesRecursively(obj[key]);
        }
      }
    }
  
    extractMessagesRecursively(data);
  
    return messages;
  }

  const errorToasterId = useId("error");
  const { dispatchToast: dispatchError } =
    useToastController(errorToasterId);
  const error = (e:string) => {
    dispatchError(
      <Toast>
        <ToastTitle>{e}</ToastTitle>
      </Toast>,
      {
        intent: "error",
      }
    );
  };
  
  useEffect(() => {
    extractMessages(mutation.error).map((e:string) => {
      error(e)
    })
  }, [mutation.isError])
  
  console.log(extractMessages(mutation.error));

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Field size="medium" label="Name" required
        >
        <Input
          appearance="outline"
          type="text"
          onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
        />
      </Field>
      <Field label="Description"
        >
        <Input
          appearance="outline"
          type="text"
          onChange={(e) => setDescription(e.target.value)}
        />
      </Field>
      <Field label="Content" required
        >
        <Input
          appearance="outline"
          type="text"
          onChange={(e) => setContent(e.target.value)}
        />
      </Field>
      <Field label="Tags "
        >
        <Input
          appearance="outline"
          type="text"
          onChange={(e) => handleTags(e.target.value)}
        />
      </Field>
      <div>
        <Button
          className={classes.primaryButton}
          appearance="primary"
          icon={<Add16Filled />}
          onClick={submitData}
        >
          Create
        </Button>
        <Button onClick={() => setComponent("home")}>Cancel</Button>
      </div>
      <Toaster toasterId={errorToasterId} position="top-end" timeout={3000} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

I am using Fluent UI 9 for my components. It would be great if there is a better way of doing this.

2. I am using React query for api requests with axios. How can i eliminate by dependency on useEffect and using the full functionality of react-query.

Answer (score 0):

I see two useEffects, and both are unnecessary.

```
useEffect(() => {
  extractMessages(mutation.error).map((e:string) => {
    error(e)
  })
}, [mutation.isError])
```

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (mutation.isSuccess) {
    setComponent("home");
  }
}, [mutation.isSuccess])
```

`useMutation` has callbacks to invoke side effects after the mutation happens, so you can do:

```
const mutation = useMutation({
  mutationFn: createQuery,
  onSuccess: () => setComponent("home"),
  onError: (err) => {
    extractMessages(err).map((e:string) => {
      error(e)
    }
  }
});
```